# How to link to root route of application

Tags: ember.js

I can't find how to make a link to the root route of my Ember app. 
I tried: `{{#link-to 'index'}}Home{{/link-to}}`, but in my console I get the exception: `Assertion failed: The attempt to link-to route 'index' failed (also tried 'index.index'). The router did not find 'index' in its possible routes: 'loading', 'error', 'start.loading', 'start.error'`

The same when I try `{{link-to 'application'}}`

This is my router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('start', { path: '/start' }, function() {
    //.. sub routes ..
  });
  this.resource('intro', { path: '/' }, function() {
    // ...
  });
  this.route('login')
});
```

Comment: Can you post your router?

Comment: I edited my question to add the router

Comment: Honestly it seems likely whatever version of ember you're using is broken.

Comment: @WillemdeWit Do you have an application route or an index route? If not, try adding an empty router with: `App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});` and the same thing for index. If that doesn't work, I agree with @kingpin2k... Sounds like you may be working with a broken version.

Comment: Turns out that I have a route with `path: '/'` which is causing my problem. I needed a route to wrap some other routes but without expanding the url. So the route is just to create a wrapping template, is there another option?

Comment: The `intro`-route was only meant to have a wrapper template for the routes it had in it. I removed the `intro`-route and fixed it with a [layout](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_layouts) on the views of the subroutes.

Comment: So `{{link-to 'Home' 'index'}}` is working, still not found why `{{link-to 'Home' 'application'}}` is not working.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Depending on what version you're using it used to just support `index` now `application` works as well for linking back to the root.

```
{{link-to 'Back to Home' 'application' }}

{{link-to 'Back to Home 2' 'index' }}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/188/edit